# Does this structure make sense in Structural Equation Modeling?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

In SEM is it acceptable to draw a path from an exogenous observable variable to an indicator of endogenous latent variable, if it is suggested in modification indices?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the fact that a modification index suggests it should be there makes it acceptable, but if your it is justifiable in your theory, then there is no reason that it shouldn't be there.